# Right way to use react router v4 in the react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am new to the react js. I have gone through lots of the tutorials for using the react router.
So, the way I am using is like this

```
**index.js**

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
const store = configureStore()

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <Main />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

**Main.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import PrivateRoute from '../../privateRoute/component/PrivateRoute';

    const LandingScreen = () => {
  return (
    <div>LandingScreen  is theere</div>
  )
}

    const LoginComponent = () => {
      return (
        <div>LoginComponent</div>
      )
    }

    export default class Main extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingScreen} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )
      }
    }
```

In **privateRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isFetching, hasUserLogIn, path, ...rest }) => {
  return localStorage.getItem("access_token") ?
    (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        path={path}
        component={Component}
      />
    )
    :
    (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: path }
        }}
      />
    )
};
```

So this way I have added the routes in my project.
So, I am confused weather I am using it in the right way or not.
Can any one suggest me or help me with this ?

Comment: You ar ehaving two intances of Router in your App, For an app wide route navigation, you should use a ssingle router instance

Comment: So, I should not use the Router history - {history}

Comment: Looking at your implementation above it probably better to remove the BrowserRouter instance

Comment: The router that I am using here is   import { Route, Redirect, Router, Switch, BrowserRouter, Provider } from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: Yeah, but where do you get `history` from

Comment: I have created that file in the directory.

Comment: import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()

export default history

Comment: Cool, then its ok to use Router with custom history and avoid using BrowserRouter. As I said, more often than not, you only need one instance of Router in your App

Comment: Okay shubham And otherwise my setup is okay or need to do more changes ?

Comment: Yes, your setup is correct apart from the Router changes that we discussed

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  I have just updated the question. Here, when there is a token in the localstorage and if it is on the localhost:3000/login then it renders the login page it should have renderd the landingscreen. On doing this it does not even call the private route.Token is just I have added . it does not even go to the privateroute.

Comment: You need to have the redirect logic in login in this case

Comment: If I type localhost:3000/login then it if token is present then it should have redirected to the Landing Page right, it should not go to the LoginPage again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set up seems good! Only thing I would note is that you're using `<Router>` to wrap your routes in one file. And then nesting that same Router in another file with `BrowserRouter` . This seems a bit duplicate.

Comment: So,what should I do , should I remove the router history = {history}

Comment: In your index.js file. you can simply remove the BrowserRouter and everything still work fine. Just use: ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: import { Route, Redirect, Router, Switch, BrowserRouter, Provider } from 'react-router-dom';
 this is the router that I am using

Comment: Right, but <Router> and <BrowserRouter> serve the same purpose. Nesting one in the other is completely unnecessary. In your current code, you have your Router set up in one component and then wrapped that component again in a BrowserRouter. You don't need both.

Comment: Okay sure Then I will remove that BrowserRouter from my app.js file

Comment: Hey Actually got one problem over here

Comment: What's the issue you're having @ganeshkaspate

Comment: I have just updated the question. Here, when there is a token in the localstorage and if it is on the localhost:3000/login then it renders the login page it should have renderd the landingscreen. On doing this it does not even call the private route

Comment: That doesn't sound like it concerns the changes we made. It sounds more like the token may have expired already which is why you were redirected to that Login route.

Comment: No it is not like that. And yes this is something else.Sorry for that. Token is just I have added . it does not even go to the privateroute.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate check out my answer regarding your localStorage issue.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your localStorage issue. Try setting up your PrivateRoute like this

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest}) => {
    return(
        <Route 
            {...rest}
            //route has a render prop that lets you create a component in-line with the route
            render = {props =>
                localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/login"/>
                )
            }
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: I think it is matching the route in switch case , Login  because of that it does not go to the privateRoute.